# Understanding GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK binding

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

While playing with compute shaders I've seen most examples just created the GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFERS, like normal buffers with:

`glGenBuffers, glBindBuffer, glBufferData`

and then they were used like this:

```
    glUseProgram(computeShader);
    glBindBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, **3**, bufferA, 0, bufferSize);
    glBindBufferRange(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, **4**, bufferB, 0, bufferSize);
    glDispatchCompute(computeShader);
```

In the compute shaders buffers were declared like this:

```
layout ( **binding = 3** ) buffer
buffer1
{
vec4    data1[];
};
layout ( **binding = 4** ) buffer
buffer2
{
vec4    data2[];
};
```

I then got some advice that after the initialization I should do something like this:

```
GLuint index = glGetProgramResourceIndex(computeShader, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, "buffer1");
    glShaderStorageBlockBinding(shader, index, index);
```

Why is this necessary ?

What purpose does it have since glBindBufferRange needs the index specified by layout(**binding = x**) ?

Comment: What are all those random ** doing in the code?

Comment: I just wanted to bold them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it has no purpose. You already explicitly set the binding in the shader - but you can do it manually too if you query the index of the shader storage block. You may wish to change it at load-time rather than hardcoding it into the shader because Shader Storage Buffer Objects are shareable using a global binding point, much like Uniform Buffer Objects.

In fact they are extraordinarily similar to UBOs, right down to an almost identical API. The real differences are that you can:

1. Write to them inside your shader (and you better use a memory barrier if you do this)
2. Use much larger storage (up to 16 MiB minimum)
3. Have variable length.

When UBOs were introduced, `ARB_shading_language_420pack` (gives `layout (binding = ...)`) had not been created yet; this may be why you are seeing advice to explicitly bind SSB indices.